# To show mat-spinner based upon file upload % in angular

Tags: angular, azure, angular-material, angular6, azure-blob-storage

I am performing `file upload` operation using **Azure Blob Storage**, Now i am able to upload the file to **Azure Blob**, But while uploading file i want show the **[mat-spinner](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview)** to user since it takes some seconds to upload.

Below is the components code:

**HTML**

```
<img src="{{Url+storageToken}}" height="100px" width="100px">
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" >
<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
<div *ngIf="filesSelected">
  <pre>{{uploadProgress$ | async | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { combineAll, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BlobService } from './az-storage/blob.service';
import { ISasToken } from './az-storage/azure.storage';

interface IUploadProgress {
  filename: string;
  progress: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  uploadProgress$: Observable<IUploadProgress[]>;
  filesSelected = false;
  Url: string;
  fileName: string;
  storageToken: string = '......storageAccessToken................';

  constructor(private blobStorage: BlobService) {}

  onFileChange(event: any): void {
    this.filesSelected = true;

    this.uploadProgress$ = from(event.target.files as FileList).pipe(
      map(file => this.uploadFile(file)),
      combineAll()
    );
    console.log(File);
  }

  uploadFile(file: File): Observable<IUploadProgress> {
    const accessToken: ISasToken = {
      container: 'upload-demo',
      filename: 'users/' + file.name,
      storageAccessToken:
        '......storageAccessToken................',
      storageUri: 'https://file-upload.blob.core.windows.net/'
    };

    this.fileName = file.name;
    this.Url = `https://file-upload.blob.core.windows.net/upload-demo/users/${this.fileName}`;

    return this.blobStorage
      .uploadToBlobStorage(accessToken, file)
      .pipe(map(progress => this.mapProgress(file, progress)));
  }

  private mapProgress(file: File, progress: number): IUploadProgress {
    return {
      filename: file.name,
      progress: progress <================ When it becomes 100%
    };
  }


}
```

Now i am displaying the **file name** and **uploading %** in the template like 
this:
[image]

**Expected Result:**

As in the the template when `onFileChange` event is called i want enable the `spinner` and when `upload % is 100%`(i,e when progress is 100%) i want close the `spinner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to use `mat-progress-spinner` update file upload progress in spinner.

**Example -**

**your.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="uploadProgress !==0 &&  uploadProgress !== 100" >
     <mat-progress-spinner class="example-margin" 
         [color]="color" [mode]="mode" [value]="uploadProgress">
    </mat-progress-spinner>
</div>

<div *ngIf="uploadProgress === 100" >
  <h1>File  upload successfully!</h1>
</div>
```

**your.component.ts**

```
uploadProgress = 0; // declare class level variable
...

private mapProgress(file: File, progress: number): IUploadProgress {
    this.uploadProgress = progress;// updating progresss of mat-spinner
    return {
      filename: file.name,
      progress: progress <================ When it becomes 100%
    };
  }
```

**[Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/kooxvkavpymk?file=app%2Fprogress-spinner-overview-example.html)**

Hope this will help!

Comment: Your solution works fine,but the: 1) `spinner is not rotating during the upload progress`. 2)`Spinner should be shown,only during upload progress but it is showing before file upload also`

Comment: you want progress spinner or only show spinner while uploading file. I have updated solution please check

Comment: Updaed demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcny5a?file=app/progress-spinner-overview-example.html

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set in the headers that you want to listen to all events in the uploadToBlobStorage method.

```
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/upload/file', file, {
  observe: 'events', (default is 'response')
});
```

You will get every event that happens in that data interchange call.

```
enum HttpEventType {
  Sent
  UploadProgress
  ResponseHeader
  DownloadProgress
  Response
  User
}
```

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEventType

Another solution is described in the official angular docs.

https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events